# How to configure subdomain on staging server in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subdomain, iis-7.5

We have a MVC application and its deployed on production and staging environment.
We want to introduce new feature in our website but it will be accessible through sub domain url. Ex if our web site address is `www.prodlive.com` then we want to access subdomain as `www.blogs.prodlive.com`

To verify this, first we need test everything on our staging environment but staging environments urls are accessible though ip address only. Example staging url is - `xx.xxx.xx.x:{port number}`. and when we tried to map subdomain with ip address, this type of host name is not allowed in IIS.

Can you please guide or give an reference how can we achieve this?

Comment: The question is how you set up the staging environment? To best mirror your production, I assume the staging server has exactly the same IIS settings like your production server, but with some DNS hacks (hosts file example) to map the same domain names to the IP address of the staging server, but it sounds like you are not doing this.

Comment: I am new to that. Can you give any reference to it please?

Comment: Could you explain you are trying to test the application with IP address or domain name? Because you mentioned the application is IP only but you are trying to bind subdomain. The format of `www.blogs.prodlive.com` is allowed in IIS so what error message did you get when you set that host name in your IIS binding.If prodlive.com is your local domain, then you only have to create a cname `www.blogs` in your loccal forward lookup zone and set host name in your IIS.If there's no IIS domain, then you can set host name in your client's hosts file.